# Stored Procedure that needs to delete from table, then compare incoming value

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm kind of stuck on how I should proceed with my stored procedure.  The idea of this SP is to take these incoming values, compare them to my User_Passwords table.  See if that table is too long based off of company policy.  Delete the old ones to shrink the table to the correct size.  Then compare the incoming password with the previous passwords to throw an error on my VB.Net code stating that they need to choose a different password because it was used before.  I've made a comment on where I'm stumped.

```
DECLARE @UserNumberOfPasswords INT
DECLARE @ua_pk uniqueidentifier = GUID
DECLARE @ResetDaysAmount INT = 30
DECLARE @AllowedNumberOfPasswords INT = 10
DECLARE @CurrentPasswordDate DATE = GetDate()
DECLARE @CurrentPassword varchar(25) = 'Password'
DECLARE @PreviousPassword BIT = 0

SELECT *
FROM User_Passwords
WHERE ua_fk = @ua_pk
ORDER BY up_PasswordDate ASC

SELECT @UserNumberOfPasswords = COUNT(*)    
FROM User_Passwords AS up
WHERE ua_fk = GUID

IF @UserNumberOfPasswords > @AllowedNumberOfPasswords
BEGIN
    WITH T
    AS (SELECT TOP (@UserNumberOfPasswords - (@AllowedNumberOfPasswords - 1)) *
        FROM   User_Passwords
        WHERE  ua_fk = @ua_pk
        ORDER BY up_PasswordDate ASC)
    DELETE FROM T; 
END

IF @UserNumberOfPasswords = @AllowedNumberOfPasswords
BEGIN
    WITH T
    AS (SELECT TOP 1 *
        FROM User_Passwords
        WHERE ua_fk = @ua_pk
        ORDER BY up_PasswordDate ASC)
    DELETE FROM T;
END

--Where I'm stumped.  I have tried to use 'up_Password' but it's throwing an error
--"the multi-part identifier "User_Passwords.up_Password" could not be bound".
--The column's type is varchar(25), just like @CurrentPassword

IF @CurrentPassword = User_Passwords.up_Password
BEGIN
    WITH T
    AS (SELECT *
        FROM User_Passwords
        WHERE ua_fk = @ua_pk
        ORDER BY up_PasswordDate ASC)
        --I know this isn't completed but I want to change the BadPassword =1
```

Later on in the SP, I'll be adding to the table, if the password is a new password.

Comment: Keep in mind, those values are there for testing, they will actually be coming from my VB code

Comment: My first question is why are you storing passwords in plain text? I realize this isn't actually part of the question but not storing passwords salted and hashed is just awful. Many people have only 2-3 passwords they use for everything.

Comment: IF @CurrentPassword = User_Passwords.up_Password   says if string = table.ColumnName. That is not valid syntax unless you are iterating over the records.

Comment: just change user_passwords.up_password to `(SELECT TOP 1 up_Password FROM User_Passwords
WHERE ua_fk = @ua_pk
ORDER BY up_PasswordDate DESC)` to get the most recent password based on the key you pass in. Also, you could just assign this to a variable in the initial select at the top of your proc. Currently that select statement does nothing for you. I think that's what you are looking to do. I also agree with @SeanLange but I think you have addressed this question in previous posts.

Comment: @SeanLange I'm only doing it for comparison.

Comment: This is not declared any where to be used in a variable `User_Passwords.up_Password`,also try doing some thing like below `if exists (select * from FROM User_Passwords
        WHERE ua_fk = @ua_pk and passwordcolumn=@CurrentPassword `..then do the rest of stuff,

Comment: LOL the fact that it is stored as plain text is the problem. But whatever, it is your users data that is not safe. Passwords should be encrypted at all times and irretrievable in plain text to protect the user. It is a one way algorithm to allow for validation, but never revealing the original value.

Comment: This was already set up prior to me joining this job.  I'm not saying you're wrong.  I'm saying that at this point, I cannot change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@SeanLange raises a **very good point**.  I would recommend you follow this up.

`IF @CurrentPassword = User_Passwords.up_Password` is not a valid statement.  [Exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) allows you to check if a query returns any results.

Here is an example:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM User_Passwords WHERE up_Password = @CurrentPassword)
    BEGIN

        PRINT 'We got one'
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN

        PRINT 'No match'
    END
```